# Passing series parameters to jqPlot via a variable

Tags: jquery, parameters, jqplot

Having to plot a graph with a varying number of lines, I'm trying to pass series parameters via a variable, but jqPlot somehow does not take them into account and keeps displaying default values for line width, color and label.
This is the simplest version of what I have tried (single line):

```
var seriesOptions = {lineWidth: 1, color: "#FF0000", label: "Call"};


var plotOptions = { 
    title: {
           text: data['stratResult'][0] + '<br /><span class="subtitle">Results</span>'
    }, 
    seriesDefaults: {
        showMarker: false
        }
    axes: {
        yaxis: {
            label: '<span class="label">Result</span>'
    }, 
                                                xaxis: {
        label: '<span class="label">Price</span>'
    }
    },
    markerOptions: { 
        show: false,
        size: 0     
    },
    series: seriesOptions,
legend: {
    show: true
    }
};


$j.jqplot('plotDiv', 
    $j.parseJSON(data['stratResult'][1]), 
    plotOptions
);
```

All other options work well, but the one passed via the seriesOptions variable shows no effect. Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Your variable seriesOptions is not supposed to be a string

Comment: @Elias Thanks, I corrected that, but the result is exactly the same ...

Comment: You're welcome, but again, according to the [documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/optionsTutorial-txt.html), series is an array of Json options, so you must add [] and it should work. If you only have one serie, it's cleaner to define the seriesDefaults property

Answer (score 0):

```
var seriesOptions = '{lineWidth: 1, color: "#FF0000", label: "Call"}';
```

**seriesOptions** must be an object, not a string, so just remove the ' '.

Also try this:

```
var plotOptions = { 
    title: {
           text: data['stratResult'][0] + '<br /><span class="subtitle">Results</span>'
    }, 
    seriesDefaults: {
        showMarker: false
        lineWidth: 1, 
        color: "#FF0000", 
        label: "Call"
    }
```

Try to place the **seriesOptions** inside the **seriesDefaults** object.

Comment: Changed that, thanks for pointing it out, however it still does not work, same problem as before.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was facing a similar problem. I had to pass the name of the series labels as a variable. I was able to resolve it by writing the seriesoptions variable like this

var seriesOptions = [{label: lab[0]},{label: lab[1]},{label: lab[2]},{label: lab[3]}];

Hope it helps